# How to generate a sequence based on a different sequence

Tags: f#

I have this sequence:

```
let wheel235 = [4; 2; 4; 2; 4; 6; 2; 6]
let wheel = seq { while true yield! wheel235 }
```

I'd like to build a second sequence that starts on a particular number, and each following number in that sequence is the previous number with the next item in the wheel sequence added to it. So if I started the sequence at 5, I would have 5, 9, 11, 15, 17, 21, 27, etc...

I can't quite wrap my head around how to do it.

For those familiar with it, it's obviously a number wheel for prime number generation, but I don't think knowing that would matter much for the answer. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with [`Seq.scan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ee340364.aspx):

```
let wheel235 = [4; 2; 4; 2; 4; 6; 2; 6]
let wheel = seq { while true do yield! wheel235 }

let result = wheel |> Seq.scan (+) 5

# result will be 5, 9, 11, 15, 17, 21, 27, etc
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, I think the result should be an inifite sequence.

Comment: @svick: I think you're probably right, but I wasn't sure from my initial reading. If that's the case then the OP could just pipe their `wheel` sequence into the `scan` rather than `wheel235`.

Comment: @svick: Just seen that you suggested that in your own answer. Upvoted :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry I meant to specify that it was infinite. Was almost 3:00am so I guess I didn't think it through enough. ;) I'd looked at scan earlier, but hadn't quite understood how it works from the MSDN description. Thanks a lot for the answers and examples.

Answer (score 3):

I think that if you want to do this just using a sequence expression, you would need to use a mutable `ref` cell:

```
let wheel = seq { 
    let result = ref 5
    yield !result
    while true do
        for x in wheel235 do
            result := !result + x
            yield !result
    }
```

But I think a better way would be to combine your code to repeat `wheel235` inifitely (after fixing the syntax error) with `Seq.scan` (as suggested bu LukeH):

```
let wheel = seq { while true do yield! wheel235 } |> Seq.scan (+) 5
```

Comment: I blame the syntax error on the hour at night as well. ;) It's correct in my code, but got lost in my simplification for the question. Thanks for the answer!